# chsh doesn't change shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I'm using CentOS 6.5, and the `chsh` command does not work. I've tried under my account and as root, each time using both the full argument `chsh -s /bin/tcsh` and using just `chsh` and following the prompts. Each time it says the shell has been changed, but it doesn't actually change--I continue to use bash.

What can I do to correct this problem?

Comment: Jeez, that's exactly what I needed. It's always something stupid. Make that an answer and I'll mark it as accepted if you'd like!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After running that command, you have to log out and back in. `chsh` changes your log in shell, not your current shell.

To change your current shell (well start a tcsh shell really), you can run `/bin/tcsh`

Comment: You are most welcome.

Comment: To add to this you can run `sudo su - $USER` that starts a new shell with your current user. Just a note that [su](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html) is actually used to run a command as a different user and `-` just starts a brand new shell with that user but you're not passing any command here so it's just starting a new shell.